# Evaluate $\underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\left( {{x}^{x}} \right)}^{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

We’ve already proven $\underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{x}^{x}}=1$ in the classroom.

Here’s my quick and dirty attempt: $\underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\left( {{x}^{x}} \right)}^{x}}={{\left( \underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{x}^{x}} \right)}^{0}}={{1}^{0}}=1$. Have I pulled this off?

What would be the simplest way to correctly evaluate this limit? I can think of $\underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\left( {{x}^{x}} \right)}^{x}}={{e}^{\underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,x\log {{x}^{x}}}}$, $\underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,x\log {{x}^{x}}=\left( \underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,x \right)\left( \underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,\log {{x}^{x}} \right)=\left( \underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,x \right)\left( \log \underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{x}^{x}} \right)=0\cdot \log 1=0$, so $\underset{x\to 0+}{\mathop{\lim }}\,{{\left( {{x}^{x}} \right)}^{x}}={{e}^{0}}=1$. This is my second attempt.

Comment: That is a dirty attempt.  You may not evaluate portions of a limit while leaving other portions untouched, moving the evaluated portions outside, so your first equality is invalid.  It will be equal to $1$, but for different reasons.

Comment: $1^0$ is not an indeterminate form. Can you prove that if $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 1$ and $g(x)$ is bounded on an interval of the form $(0,a)$ then $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)^{g(x)} = 1$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Isn't OP just using [limit properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties) like $\lim [(f(x))^{g(x)}] = (\lim f(x))^{\lim g(x)}$ in the first attempt, and $\lim (f(x) g(x)) = (\lim f(x))(\lim g(x))$ in the second attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [L'Hospital's rule](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/lhospitalsrule.aspx). The original limit is of the indeterminate form $0^0$ so we let
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x^x)^x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{x^2}.$$
Then
$$\ln L = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{x^2}},$$
which is now of the indeterminate form $-\infty/\infty.$ Applying L'Hospital's rule gives
$$\ln L = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac 1x}{\frac {-2}{x^3}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}{\frac{x^2}{-2}}=0.$$

Therefore
$$L = e^{\ln L}=e^0 = 1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(x^{x})^{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^{x^{2}}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}(x^{2})^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\ \stackrel{u=\frac{x^{2}}{2}}{=} \lim_{u\to 0^{+}}(2u)^{u}=\lim_{u\to 0^{+}}2^{u}\lim_{u\to 0^{+}}u^{u}=2^{0}\cdot 1 = \boxed{1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The first way is fine, no real need for overcomplication. The exponentiation $(a,b)\mapsto a^b$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)\times \Bbb R$, therefore as long as $g(x)\to \alpha\in\Bbb R$ and $f(x)\to\beta>0$, you can evaluate the limit $f(x)^{g(x)}\to \beta^\alpha$ by substitution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\left ( x^x \right )^x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\operatorname{exp}\left \{ \ln\left ( x^x \right )^x \right \}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\operatorname{exp}\left \{ x\ln \left ( x^x \right ) \right \}=\operatorname{exp}\left \{ 0\ln \left ( \operatorname{exp}\left \{ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{1/x} \right \} \right ) \right \}=\operatorname{exp}\left \{ 0 \right \}=1$$

Comment: questionable step in there